# How can I make dot_indicator in flutter with limited dots and a + sign for indicating 100+ images. [ SEE IMAGE ]

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image]

How can i make this in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

as you didnt provide any snippet code, then i assume you have more than 100 image in list.

you can use `List.take()`

```
List imageList = [];

Row(children:[
   ...imageList.take(3).toList().asMap().map((key, value) {
       return MapEntry(key, YourDotsWidget());
    }).values.toList(),
   imageList.length > 3 
      ? YourPlusIconWidget()
      : SizedBox()
])
```

with this, you will only show the first 3 item in list, and if the length is morethan 3, its show `PlusIconWidget`

actually you can also use `getRange()`, but it will `throw` error if the list length less than the limit.